# How to connect eclipse IDE to apache Ignite?

Tags: spring, ignite

I have written Ignite hello world program in Eclipse and want to connect it to localhost(127.0.0.1). But it is giving me error for example "ignite.xml file path is invalid"

I am starting ignition as follows,

```
try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) {}
```

But I got error like:

> Spring XML configuration path is invalid: examples/config/example-ignite.xml.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried a valid Spring XML path?

Answer (score 3):

You have the following options:

- Provide the absolute file path.
- Set `IGNITE_HOME` system property or environment variable, put the file in this folder and provide the path relative to the home.
- Add the configuration file on classpath under `META-INF` and provide the path relative to it.

The last option is usually the most convenient for the applications with an embedded Ignite node.

Comment: I set Ignite_Home property in eclipse and export that property also. But still got same error. which configuration file should be added? I install apache-ignite in etc directory, so path is /etc/apache-ignite-fabric-1.6.0-bin.

Comment: Where is the configuration file located?